# Allow User's Manager to see Private records?

Tags: security, approval-process, owd

I currently have a custom object which is set to private in organization-wide default sharing settings. I have created an approval process to allow managers to approve private records.

When the Manager of a user attempts to approve the record, they receive an "Insufficient Privileges" message.  Also, when navigating to the object tab, the manager cannot see the records created by their subordinates.

I currently do not have role hierarchies set up in the org. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anyone still looking this, The previous answer is kind of obsolete now and custom apex is not required a FLOW can do the JOB.
Option 1 : In the sharing settings enable Manager Group (If enabled, users can share records with their managers and manager subordinates groups) [see this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.users_managers_only.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)

Option 2 : Use Flow to create a share record with required values to give the visibility.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If there is no role setup for your org Grant Access Using Hierarchies does not work.

**Option 1:**  Give the manager view all and manage all access (if it is ok to expose all data to the managers). 
To do this go to their profile and in the object permissions provide view all and modify all next to the create read edit and delete checkbox for the object
If Grant Access Using Hierarchies is deselected, users that are higher in the role or territory hierarchy don’t receive automatic access. However, some users—such as those with the “View All” and “Modify All” object permissions and the **“View All Data” and “Modify All Data” system permissions**—can still access records they don’t own.

**Option 2:** Ask the users to manually share the data with the manager
When you check the buttons once sharing is set to private you can see a sharing button using which you can add a user/ public group who needs to have access to the record.

Comment: Option 3: Have Apex Code create the share for the user automatically when the record is created or ownership changes so that the manager always has sufficient access.

Comment: I was just thinking of that SFDCfox! I just wasn't sure if APEX would let you modify metadata related to security. Also, I wanted to try to avoid writing APEX as I'm still kind of new at it and needed a solution in a pinch. But, I guess you've got to start at some point or another.